# Spark kryo serialization register Datatype[]

Tags: serialization, apache-spark, kryo

To force spark to use kryo serialization the following option can be set `spark.kryo.registrationRequired`.

How can I register `org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType[]`?

```
Class is not registered: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType[]
```

which is throwing an exception. But trying to register like `classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType[]]` will not compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was confused with java and scala array notation.

```
classOf[Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType]]
```

is the correct registration.

Nonetheless, this is a spark internal class which should already be registered by spark.